# Where is the csrftoken stored in Django database?

Tags: python, django, django-csrf, csrf-token

Where is the `csrftoken` stored?

When I access an API endpoint (logout API, it do not need the params):

```
POST /rest-auth/logout/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.10.10.105:8001
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Authorization: Token 0fe2977498e51ed12ddc93026b08ab0b1a06a434
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.146 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:8080/register
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: sessionid=b95zopro0qvkrexj8kq6mzo1d3z2hvbl; csrftoken=z53lKL0f7VHkilYS5Ax8FMaQCU2ceouje9OeTJOgTy4gH0UgHVltAlOe2KFNNNB6
```

the header is upper. In the Response I get an error:

```
{"detail":"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}
```

So, the backend must have verified the `csrftoken`.

In the backend database, I can not find the `csrftoken` field:

[image]

So I want to know where it is saved in the encrypted `session_data`?

Comment: By default the csrf token is stored in a cookie. You won't find it in the database. If you want to store it in the session data you can set [CSRF_USE_SESSIONS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-CSRF_USE_SESSIONS).

Comment: but if backend do not store `csrftoken` how can it verify it?

Comment: You can't. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#is-it-a-problem-that-django-s-csrf-protection-isn-t-linked-to-a-session-by-default .

Comment: You can except `csrf` validation if you are at DRF OR Any API.

Comment: where do you need the csrf_token for?

Comment: @KingReload Now, I want to get the `csrftoken` in the frontend and set it to request header `x-csrftoken`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49312473/how-can-i-get-the-cookies-csrftoken-in-axios-interceptors-requests-config

Answer (score 5):

Given this [QA](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#is-posting-an-arbitrary-csrf-token-pair-cookie-and-post-data-a-vulnerability) in the `django` docs, you can see that the framework by default uses the *Double Submit Cookie* approach (rather than the *synchronizer* pattern).

This approach does not require the server to store the `CSRF` token, as the only check it does is comparing the token within the cookie with the one in the header (or parameter) and verify that they are equal.

The *synhronizer* pattern, on the other hand, does store the `CSRF` token somewhere in the server, and for each request it verifies its validity by comparing it with the one sent over the header ( or as before, in a POST parameter ).

You can read more about the two approaches [here](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html).

---

I guess you are testing your API with a web service testing application, in which case you are missing the second token somewhere in your request.

[This section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#ajax) explains how to place the token for `AJAX` calls:

> AJAX
>   While the above method can be used for AJAX POST requests, it has some inconveniences: you have to remember to pass the CSRF token in as POST data with every POST request. For this reason, there is an alternative method: on each XMLHttpRequest, set a custom X-CSRFToken header to the value of the CSRF token. This is often easier, because many JavaScript frameworks provide hooks that allow headers to be set on every request.

Seeing your request above, therefore you should place this header (with the value of the current token, of course):

```
X-CSRFToken: z53lKL0f7VHkilYS5Ax8FMaQCU2ceouje9OeTJOgTy4gH0UgHVltAlOe2KFNNNB6
```

Comment: see my this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49312473/how-can-i-get-the-cookies-csrftoken-in-axios-interceptors-requests-config  I can not get the Cookies' `csrftoken`.  I don't know why.