# How can I get the Cookies' `csrftoken` in `Axios.interceptors.request`'s config?

Tags: javascript, axios

How can I get the Cookies' `csrftoken` in `Axios.interceptors.request`'s config?

```
Axios.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {

    if (
      config.method === "post" ||
      config.method === "put" ||
      config.method === "delete"||
      config.method === "get"
    ) {

    }


    if (Cookies.get('token')!==undefined) {   
      config.headers['Authorization']= 'Token '+Cookies.get('token');
    }
    // there I try to get the `csrftoken` in the Cookies, but I can not get.
    if (Cookies.get('csrftoken')!==undefined) {   

      config.headers['x-csrftoken']= Cookies.get('csrftoken');  // 'CSRFToken'
    }

    return config;
  },
  error => {  
    return Promise.reject(error.data.error.message);
  }
);
```

In the `Axios.interceptors.request`'s config I can not get Cookies's `csrftoken`: `Cookies.get('csrftoken')`.

my AxiosConfig code is bellow:

```
AxiosConfig:{
    baseURL: 'http://10.10.10.105:8001/',

    responseType: "json",
    withCredentials: true,  // there will send the Cookie (with it there are: sessionid, csrftoken)

    xsrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',  // default: XSRF-TOKEN
    xsrfHeaderName: 'x-csrftoken',   // default: X-XSRF-TOKEN
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
    }
  }
```

---

**edit-1**

There is the `csrftoken` in the Cookie.

[image]

---

**edit-2**

And in the cookie, there is no `csrftoken` too.

[image]

---

**edit-3**

if I get the `document.cookie` in console, I will get the `""`:
```

> document.cookie
>   < ""
>   ```

---

**edit-4**

in my Django backend, the `settings.py`:

INSTALLED_APPS:

```
...
'corsheaders', 

'rest_framework',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'rest_framework_docs',   
'rest_auth',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'rest_auth.registration',
...
```

I am not sure whether the `rest_auth` and `allauth` will affect the `csrftoken`.

Comment: what does it mean `I cannot get it`? Is it undefined? An error is thrown? which error?

Comment: it is undefined.

Comment: alright if you `console.log(Cookies.get('csrftoken');` within the interceptor, what does it say?

Comment: @MarkoPacak its undefined.

Comment: in the browser js console, type `document.cookie`. what do you see? (paste the exact line)

Comment: `document.cookie` get empty string. 
""

Comment: edit 1 and 2 are in contrast with each other...

Comment: @MarkoPacak See my post this line: `withCredentials: true,  // there will send the Cookie (with it there are: sessionid, csrftoken)`.  if I set false, the header will not give the Cookie option. So, I am also suspect the Axios, whether it store the sessionid and csrftoken. why you see the sessionid is because there are the second time to login yestoday.

Comment: try not use the axios config at all. by seeing my older projects I have set up none. Besides that, I do not think I can help you anymore

Answer (score 3):

First of all, always make sure that the cookie is not flagged as [httpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly).

If it is, your `javascript` code won't be able to read / modify its content.

You can check the cookies tab in your browser and you will see whether it's readable or not.

In in your case though, `django` shouldn't be setting the flag as `httpOnly` as the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#acquiring-the-token-if-csrf-use-sessions-is-false) describe how to read the value in `javascript` directly from the cookie.

A few things I can point out by experience:

- The config object might not yet be filled with the data when you receive it within an interceptor. Therefore setting `config.headers = ...;` might trigger an error.

Make sure you write:

```
config.headers = config.headers || {};
```

before setting the `headers` so no *'config.headers is undefined'* will be triggered.

- Alternatively to directly reading the cookie, store the `csrf` value inside an hidden `input` as per default procedure.

You can do something like this (syntax might be incorrect):

```
<input type="hidden"
   name="csrftoken"
   value="{% csrf_token %}"/>
</div>
```

and then send the token within the interceptor with:

```
config.headers['x-csrftoken'] = document.querySelector('input[name="csrftoken"]').value;
```

In such case, since you do not need to read the cookie, it would be a **huge plus** to set it as `httpOnly`.

Comment: I use the Django/Django-Rest-Framework as the backend. the httpOnly default is False. And in the cookie store tab, there is no `csrftoken` and `sessionid`.

Comment: In the backend, there also used the `django-auth` and `all-auth`. but I am not sure whether this will affect that.

Comment: and my frontend is written by `Vue.js`, will the `<input type="hidden"
   name="csrftoken"
   value="{% csrf_token %}"/>
</div>`template  still work?

Comment: only if it is generated with `jinja`. i dont believe it is your case

Answer (score 0):

Axios has an [order of precedence](https://github.com/axios/axios#config-order-of-precedence) to config settings, so it could be possible that settings are overwritten by other code.

For example in *Chrome* browser, you can open the dev tools pane, click the Applications tab, and then on the left-side, you can click Cookies to view those to make sure the correct ones exist:

[image]

If you have an Axios `request interceptor` that defines the `XSRF-TOKEN` header, it would be overwritten by this:

```
axios.post(route('logout'), undefined, {
    headers: {
        'XSRF-TOKEN': 'bad',
    },
});
```

If you have a file, such as you would in many Laravel/Vue projects, called `bootstrap.js` or `axios.js` that declares global config settings, that setting could be overwritten by an interceptor.

For example:

```
// document head
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

...

// axios.js or bootstrap.js (imported in SPA app's main.js file)
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

const token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    // an interceptor would overwrite this due to right-to-left precedence
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['XSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

That last example there is very important because, that would be used for calling internal APIs. If you are calling an external API that utilizes CORS, such as Google, they can require specific headers and other headers can cause errors to be thrown.

To temporarily overwrite headers, you can use a pattern such as this where you are calling the external API:

```
// temporarily wipe 'XSRF-TOKEN' header for Google CORS
const instance = axios.create();

instance.defaults.headers.common = {};
instance.defaults.headers.common.accept = 'application/json';

const { data } = await instance.get('https://www.external.com/foobars');
```

That would overwrite an interceptor as well because `instance` by design takes precedence over global defaults.

Here is the `request interceptor` that I use:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

/**
 * Request interceptor: for each request to the server,
 * attach the CSRF token if it exists.
 *
 */
axios.interceptors.request.use(async (request) => {
    try {
        const csrf = Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN');
        request.withCredentials = true;

        if (csrf) {
            request.headers.common['XSRF-TOKEN'] = csrf;
        }

        return request;
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(`axios# Problem with request during pre-flight phase: ${err}.`);
    }
});
```

Since CSRF requires to be accessible by JavaScript, it must **not** be `httpOnly`, so rather than using a library such as `js-cookie`, you can get the cookie using `document.cookie`, but that returns a semicolon-delimited string of key/value pairs, so you could exercise your mind by making a function that extracts the CSRF.

```
console.log('cookies', document.cookie)
```

Bonus reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/get
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/set